# How to avoid elements to overlay each other in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, overlay

I am quit new to flutter, and I tried a lot of classes and properties in order avoinding overlay icons on each other as you can see in the photo:
[image]

I need that all the icons will be spread on each card, but with respect to other icons on the same card. What I need to do to make it work?

**Class GameCard:**

```
 class GameCard extends StatefulWidget {
  GameCard(this.cardSymbols) {
    rows = (cardSymbols.length / cols).ceil();
  }

  final List<int> cardSymbols;

  int rows;
  final cols = 3;
  Random random = new Random();
  List<int> randomNumbers = [];

  @override
  State<GameCard> createState() => _GameCardState();
}

// todo: fit table to picture
class _GameCardState extends State<GameCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            image: Image.asset(
              'assets/images/GameCard.png',
            ).image),
      ),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Table(
        columnWidths: const <int, TableColumnWidth>{
          0: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
          1: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
          2: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
        },
        children: <TableRow>[
          for (int i = 0, index = 0; i < widget.cols; i++)
            TableRow(children: <Widget>[
              for (int j = 0; j < widget.rows; j++, index++)
                Transform(
                    transform:
                        Matrix4.rotationZ(widget.random.nextInt(1000) / 100),
                    child: Transform.scale(
                        scale: widget.random.nextInt(2).toDouble() + 1,
                        child: Cell(widget.cardSymbols[index]))),
            ])
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Class Cell:**

```
  class Cell extends StatefulWidget {
  IconData icon;
  Color color;
  final index;
  Cell(this.index)
  {
    icon = ClassicTheme.getIcon(index);
    color = ClassicTheme.getColor(index);
  }

  @override
  State<Cell> createState() => _CellState();
}


class _CellState extends State<Cell> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 64,
      width: 32,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(widget.icon),
        color: widget.color,
        onPressed: iconClicked,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your container child property use `ListView` widget or `GridView` widget to order your icons as per you need.

In your case you can choose GridView widget and it having horizontal spacing and vertical spacing. so you can able to align as your need.

I have paste the document link below.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html

Comment: Hey, 
Thank you for the answer. I have already tried this, but when I am adding the Transform class then still I get the same result where icons overlay each other... I do need them to be scattered and rotated on each card, so I have to use the Transform class (and not arranged like a table)